# Setting multiple Phing properties from command line

Tags: phing

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="first" basedir="." default="build-skeleton">

    <property name="dirName" value="module" />
    <property name="fileName" value="config" />

    <target name="build-skeleton" description="Making folders">
        <mkdir dir="./${dirName}/Block" />
        <touch file="./${dirName}/etc/${fileName}.xml" />
    </target>

</project>
```

`phing -f mage_module.xml -DdirName=moduleX,fileName=config`
`phing -f mage_module.xml -DdirName=moduleX fileName=config`

Both throw an error - no surprise there.

**Is it possible to set multiple properties in Phing via command line?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just repeating the -D parameter should work:

```
phing -f mage_module.xml -DdirName=moduleX -DfileName=config
```

Comment: if you use the "if" and "unless" attributes, just set the variable with no value. xml: `<... if="test" >` read by `phing -Dtest`